# Import VPN config files to NetworkManager from command line

Tags: command-line, vpn, networkmanager, openvpn, nmcli

One can import `.ovpn` files to NetworkManager through GUI tool `nm-connection-editor` (right click on `nm-applet` and click on `Edit connections`): `Add` -> `Import a saved VPN configuration...`.

My goal is to do same thing but via command line using tools like `nm-cli`. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I am trying to do the same thing so will post an answer if I get it working.

Comment: @DavidMason, unfortunately, no. I'm waiting for your solution.

Comment: I'm looking actively for for a solution too.

Comment: I'd like to see a solution for importing by command line

Answer (score 21):

I'm using nmcli version 1.2.6 and I can use it to import openvpn configs.

```
nmcli connection import type openvpn file ~/myconfig.ovpn
```

From now on even in NetworkManager UI my vpn is visible.

To further configure the connection you can use the `show`command to find out the connection name and `modify` to change config values.

```
nmcli connection show
nmcli connection modify myvpnconnectionname +vpn.data username=myusername
```

Comment: any idea how to use `-vpn.data` if I accidentally added something wrong to the configuration data?

Comment: @32r34wgf3e don't know. When my configuration is wrong I delete it and do a fresh set up from the command line as outlined in my answer. Tip: Store your commands in a text file for later reuse.

Comment: You just pointed me to the right direction with "modify", thank you sir.

Answer (score 6):

A workaround I use to get past the lack of functionality that comes with nmcli on debian-based systems is to use commands to copy an existing VPN config file in the /etc/NetworkManager/system-settings folder to a new file (as root, of course) in the same folder and make string replacements to the permitted user, gateway, username and password values in the new copy.  Then I restart network manager to apply the changes.

**For example:**

A typical config file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-settings folder might look as such:

```
[connection]
id=<<id>>
uuid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
type=vpn
permissions=user:<<permissions_user>>:;
autoconnect=false

[vpn]
password-flags=0
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
require-mppe-128=yes
mppe-stateful=yes
user=<<user>>
refuse-eap=yes
refuse-chap=yes
gateway=<<gateway>>
refuse-pap=yes

[vpn-secrets]
password=<<password>>

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

... so you can just create a new config file that looks similar to the one above...

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-settings
cp "existing-working-vpn-config-file" "new-vpn-config-file"
```

...then replace the '<<>>' values above with your own VPN settings, eg:

```
sed -i "s/<<permissions_user>>/my_permissions_user/g" new-vpn-config-file
sed -i "s/<<user>>/my_user/g" new-vpn-config-file
sed -i "s/<<gateway>>/my_gateway/g" new-vpn-config-file
sed -i "s/<<password>>/my_password/g" new-vpn-config-file
```

... and then finally restart network manager via the following command:

```
service network-manager restart
```

Note: The UUID setting doesn't seem to matter, even if it's non-unique.  No idea why.  Stuff just works.

Also, If you are adding a new file rather than copying, make sure the permissions to the file are set to 600 (read and write), and the owner is root.

Give it a shot and tell me what you think.  It works for me, all via command line.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to run from root:

```
USER=japie
runuser -l $USER -c "sudo -S nmcli connection import type openvpn file ~/vpn_clients/flappie3-TO-IPFire.ovpn"
```

> Connection 'flappie3-TO-IPFire' (26d0b28e-9212-4e71-90dc-3911ddf231e5)
>   successfully added.

Comment: Why use `runuser` only to have the user use `sudo`? This does not add anything not already mentioned in e.g. [Import VPN config files to NetworkManager from command line](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/359923)

Comment: laptop enrollment script runs as root

Comment: Sure, and the you switch to `japie` using `runuser`, but then you switch back to root with `sudo`...

Comment: if you don't add "sudo ..." the current user/japie doesn't have enough rights to run nmcli

Comment: So don't switch to that user with `runas` then... In short what I'm saying is that it ought to be enough with `nmcli connection import type openvpn file ~japie/vpn_clients/flappie3-TO-IPFire.ovpn`.

Comment: The enrollment script is running as root and needs to pretend to have elevated rights and pseudo user tty. Just try it. And there multiple ways of achieving the same result. Using sed to change a specific file only works until the file parameters change. Using nmcli might hold longer.