# How to edit a VPN using the terminal user interface of NetworkManager (nmtui)?

Tags: networkmanager, vpn

I know that "normal" network interfaces (wired, Wi-Fi, etc.) can be edited using the NetworkManager's command `nmtui`. For example:

> ```
> nmtui
> ```
>
> [image: NetworkManager terminal user interface nmtui menu]

Having said from this menu you can select `Activate a connection` and see the list of all your connections (including VPNs) and activate/deactiavate them:

> [image]
>
> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_ip_networking_with_nmtui

The problem is that your VPN connections are not shown under "Edit a connection" so I do not understand how to Edit VPN connections using `nmtui`. Use case: this could be very useful to delegate this kind of management to administrators on a non-graphical server without "brilliant skills" with the command line. That's why I suggest to use `nmcli` or editing files manually instead, but maybe I'm over-complicating things.

At the moment I tried this version on CentOS:

```
NetworkManager --version
1.18.8-1.el7
```

And I've also tried this version on Ubuntu focal and Debian GNU/Linux:

```
NetworkManager --version
1.22.10
```

And in both versions when I select "Edit a connection" in `nmtui` I'm not able to see any VPN.

### Question

How do you edit VPN connections with `nmtui` (for example to change the server, port, etc.)?

Is there any missing package or whatever to do it?

It seems to me that you can just Activate or Deactivate a VPN but I may be wrong and maybe `nmcli` and manual setup are not the only ways.

Thank you for this clarification.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK at the moment (2022) all the listed Network Manager VPN plugins does not add any "Edit" capability to the `nmtui` tool for VPN connections:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/VPN

That's why you are able to list them but not edit them from `nmtui`.

If you have lot of time and `C` skills you may want to add support to it, forking the NetworkManager source code and checking out the `nmtui` directory:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager
- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/tree/main/src/nmtui

Or you can just use `nmcli` instead of `nmtui` for minor changes, or manual configuration editing for great changes. The documentation on both is great. E.g.

- [Use nmcli to modify VPN password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335999/use-nmcli-to-modify-vpn-password)
- [Import VPN config files to NetworkManager from command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140163/import-vpn-config-files-to-networkmanager-from-command-line)

BTW I could still be wrong about `nmtui`. Maybe there will be more answers about it.